# apache2 setup bosh for openfire

Tags: apache2, xmpp

I am having issues setting up a BOSH service for a webchat. As XMPP server I'm using OpenFire and I'm already able to connect to the server using the Pidgin client. What I've done is the following:
First of all I've enabled the proxy using `a2enmod proxy proxy_http`. Then I went to edit the `proxy.conf` and added these in the end

```
ProxyVia On
ProxyErrorOverride On
ProxyPass /http-bind http://localhost:7070/http-bind
ProxyPassReverse /http-bind http://localhost:7070/http-bind
```

However, when i try to reach `http://example.com/http-bind` I get the following:

```
HTTP ERROR: 400

Problem accessing /http-bind/. Reason:

Bad Request

Powered by Jetty://
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No any error in fact.
While you see the result, which measn that all proxy settings of yours are correct, as the http-bind needs to accept the POST(xml format) data as its true request, it is why the openfire server return 404 to you.